# SUMIFS function with a criteria for substring match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm having trouble figuring out how to write a SUMIFS function with a criteria for a substring match. I can do it with an exact match as follows:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"=match")
```

This would sum all rows in column A, if the corresponding row in column B matches the text "match" exactly.

What if I want to perform a substring match on column B instead of a direct match? That is, sum all rows in column A as long as the corresponding row in column B *contains* the text "match"? How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcards. For example

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"*match*")
```

[image]